# VB.NET help in Prime Number

Tags: vb.net, windows

Using VB.NET windows application I am trying to do following stuff : 
I have 2 ListBoxes ListBox1 and ListBox2. There are some numbers are inside ListBox1. If I simply click on the Button I want to add all prime numbers in ListBox2. I really unable to do that now. Please help me here.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code that you have written to solve the problem and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Help with *what* exactly?  Looping thru the items? determining Primes? Adding numbers?

Comment: There's a fast algorithm to get all the prime numbers in an array called the Erathostene's Sieve. Search for it.

Comment: http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this (change button and listbox names if needed) -

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each item As Integer In ListBox1.Items
        If IsPrime(item) Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Public Shared Function IsPrime(subject As Integer) As Boolean
    If (subject And 1) = 0 Then
        If subject = 2 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End If
    Dim i As Integer = 3
    While (i * i) <= subject
        If (subject Mod i) = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
        i += 2
    End While
    Return subject <> 1
End Function
```

Comment: Yes!! it is working fine. Thanks Farahn. I really don't understand how to read the the items without selecting.